# Could not set BootOrder: No space left on device

Tags: boot, debian, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader

When I boot my HP computer, these messages appear:

```
System BootOrder not found.
Initializing defaults …
Could not create variable: … Out of resources
```

After 2 failed attempts (Out of resources), Grub finally loads so I can choose between Debian and Windows Boot Loader.

From debian:

```sh
% efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
Boot0000* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0002* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\shimx64.efi)
Boot0006* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
…
Boot0206* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0207* debian        HD(2,GPT,acd21fe6-e872-42dd-a40a-82e3eae6323f,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\shimx64.efi)
```

I would like to set a boot order to avoid this fool entry creation, however:

```sh
% efibootmgr -o 0,1
Could not set BootOrder: No space left on device
```

By the way, I would like to clean all these duplicated entries. `% efibootmgr -b 202 -B` seems to work, but it takes about 90s, and I have around 500 entries to remove…

Hardware: HP ProBook 4540s

EDIT:

```sh
% apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
…
Paramétrage de grub-efi-amd64 (2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u3) ...
Installation pour la plate-forme x86_64-efi.
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[143842]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5604: grub-install
File descriptor 5 (/dev/sda2) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5604: grub-install
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[143842]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5604: grub-install
File descriptor 5 (/dev/sda2) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5604: grub-install
grub-install : attention : Cannot set EFI variable BootOrder.
grub-install : attention : efivarfs_set_variable: writing to fd 7 failed: Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique.
grub-install : attention : _efi_set_variable_mode: ops->set_variable() failed: Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique.
grub-install : erreur : failed to register the EFI boot entry: Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique.
Failed: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --force-extra-removable 
WARNING: Bootloader is not properly installed, system may not be bootable
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
…
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour shim-signed:amd64 (1.33+15+1533136590.3beb971-7) ...
Erreur : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

Now, there are no more duplicated `debian` entries, but I still can’t set a boot order.

Comment: Can you try just rebooting a few times? Various EFI firmwares handle "out of flash memory space" conditions differently, but I've heard that at least on some of them, the flash garbage collection only occurs at boot time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think this was a BIOS security issue.

Press/Hammer `Escape` key as soon as PC starts to access to BIOS menu, then `F10` to configure BIOS/UEFI.

In `System Configuration` tab, you have to access `Set Security Level`, then for various options (e.g. `UEFI Boot Order`), you have to select `Change` instead of `View` item.
In fact, UEFI lets you change anything but removes all settings you have set as soon as you restart your PC if you had not set above settings to `Change`.

I think one of this setting used to protect NVRAM from editing with `efibootmgr`.